# Sistema de login e senha que verifique data [PHP]

Tags: php

Boa noite!

Estou trabalhando em um projeto em PHP, e me deparei com uma barreira, bem na parte final do meu sistema:

É bem simples até, funciona assim:

1- ADMIN cadastra usuário, senha e atribui uma data de expiração do plano; (concluído)

2 - USUÁRIO se depara com uma tela de login e senha para acesso ao painel VIP; (concluído)

3 - SISTEMA verifica, com base na data que o ADMIN colocou para expirar, se a data de expiração do USUÁRIO é maior que a data do dia de hoje; (agarrei aqui)

Já está tudo pronto praticamente, o que me falta é uma forma do sistema conferir, junto com login e senha, se a data de expiração do usuário > data de hoje, caso for, ele não permite que o usuário faça o login e exibe uma mensagem dizendo ao usuário para contatar um ADMIN.

Eu não tenho nenhum curso de PHP, o conhecimento que possuo é todo vindo do YouTube e por isso não consegui achar nenhuma função que me auxilie a fazer isso.

O código do meu login e senha:

```
<?php

include('conexao.php');  // conecta com o banco de dados

session_start(); // starta a sessão

$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['usuario']);  // define a variável usuário como sendo aquilo que está dentro do post do formulário 


$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['senha']);  // define a váriavel senha como sendo aquilo que está dentro do post da senha


$query = "select * from usuarios where usuario = '{$usuario}' and senha = '{$senha}' ";  // query para selecionar tudo do banco de dados dos usuarios e verificar se possui um usuário e senha de fato

$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);   // faz a conexão da query com o banco de dados

$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);  // verifica o número de linhas encontradas


if($row == 1) {      // caso encontrada 1 linha, então o usuário está cadastrado

    
    
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;    // se o usuário está cadastrado, inicia uma sessão com seu nome

    header('Location: conteudo');   // manda o usuário para a página do conteúdo VIP 

    

} else {       // se não está cadastrado
    $_SESSION['nao_autenticado'] = true;    // abre uma sessão nao autenticado
    header('Location: login.php');    //  volta o usuário para a página de login
    exit();     // finaliza
}  


?>
```

Coisas que eu tentei:

- Eu tentei inserir um else if (não sei direito pra que serve, mas parece que é uma condição a mais) junto com o "verificar se há uma linha", mas não obtive sucesso, a página retornou toda errada e em branco, então acho que nem vale a pena postar o código aqui.
- Eu fiz o seguinte código dentro do painel VIP:

```
<?php

                  
                   include('conexao.php');

               
                  $sql="SELECT (data) from usuarios where usuario = '{$_SESSION['usuario']}'";
                  $result=mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);

                  while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                  ?>

                  <?php

                  $dt_atual = date("Y-m-d"); // data atual
                  $timestamp_dt_atual = strtotime($dt_atual); // converte para timestamp Unix
                   
                  $dt_expira = $mostrar['data']; // data de expiração do plano
                  $timestamp_dt_expira = strtotime($dt_expira); // converte para timestamp Unix
                   
                  // data atual é maior que a data de expiração
                  if ($timestamp_dt_atual > $timestamp_dt_expira){ // true
                    echo  "Plano Expirado!";
                    session_destroy();
                    header ('location: index.php');
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['expira'] = true;
                 }
                  else // false
                    echo "Seu Plano Está Ativo!";
  
                  ?>
```

Esse até funciona, mas o usuário consegue acesso direto ao painel VIP e as informações contidas nele, e apenas quando atualiza que o sistema retorna para a página de login, acho que não funciona portanto.

Qualquer resposta já me ajuda demais, talvez uma função ou algo do tipo. Só falta essa verificação para meu sistema funcionar 100%, fico muito grato a atenção de todos!!

Informações adicionais:

- Não possuo nenhum problema na tabela mysql que está guardando os dados dos usuários;
- A tabela mysql chama-se usuarios;
- A tabela mysql contém:  ID \ NOME \ SENHA \ CELULAR \ DATA DE EXPIRAÇÃO de cada usuário.

---

Esqueci de mencionar que o problema em questão é o fato do usuário que está com o plano vencido, conseguir acesso ao painel VIP da mesma forma que o usuário que pagou em dia.

Um exemplo:

João pagou para usar meu sistema por 30 dias, após esses 30 dias João não pode mais ter acesso ao painel VIP, portanto o sistema em questão faria a verificação da data de João com o dia de hoje e apenas levaria João até o painel VIP caso o ADMIN tenha renovado o plano de João por mais 30 dias.

Comment: 1) desnecessário session_destroy()... limpe os dados de $_SESSION ou atualize-os...... se você usa o $_SESSION['expira'], ele deve ser colocado ANTES do redirect... como está ele nunca será setado.... inclua a verificação de DATA junto com o outro código... deixe tudo em um lugar.... tem muito mais coisas a melhorar, mas basicamente é isso! espero ter ajudado...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, dei uma estudada a mais, procurei, pesquisei no YouTube e afins. Consegui fazer meu sistema funcionar perfeitamente... Creio que agora vai ser a primeira solução a estar disponível no SO ou em qualquer outro fórum similar.

Vou deixar o código comentado abaixo, qualquer dúvida a mais sobre esse sistema ou algo parecido, disponibilizo meu email: lucascopatti99@hotmail.com para contato!

Vamos lá:

```
include('conexao.php');   // inclui a conexão com o banco de dados

session_start();   // starta a sessão


$datadehoje = date("Y-m-d"); // pega a data de hoje e insere na variável

$timestamp_dt_atual = strtotime($datadehoje);    // aqui transformamos a data de hoje em timestamp unix, um modelo padrão 


$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['usuario']);  // pega o que tiver no post usuario e joga na variável usuario

$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['senha']); // pega o que tiver no post senha e joga na variável senha


$query = "select * from usuarios where usuario = '{$usuario}' and senha = '{$senha}' ";   // abre uma query, selecionando tudo dentro de usuários onde o usuario for o que tiver na variavel usuario ( ou seja, o que for digitado no post usuario )

$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);  // passa a conexão entre query e banco de dados

$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);    // faz a contagem do numero de rows (linhas) encontradas no result

if($row == 1){     // se tiver 1 linha ( ou seja, achou o usuário e senha correspondentes)

$sql= "SELECT (data) from usuarios where usuario = '$usuario'";  // vai selecionar a data do usuario que tiver na variavel
     
$sqlpassar = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql); // passamos a conexao entre a query novamente
    
$rowzinha = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlpassar);   // aqui vamos pegar o array da variavel anterior
     
$roz = $rowzinha['data'];   // vamos falar que a variavel $roz é o array da data, ou seja, vai selecionar a data daquele usuário

$timestamp_dt_expira = strtotime($roz);   // vamos converter novamente a variavel (roz) que guarda a data do usuário para timestamp unix


}else{                         // se não achar uma linha ( em possibilidade do usuario errar a senha, login ou similar ) 

    $_SESSION['nao_autenticado'] = true;    // abre uma sessão nao autenticado para o usuario

    header('Location: login.php');   // manda ele de volta para o login

    exit();   // finaliza
}

if ($timestamp_dt_expira > $timestamp_dt_atual){   // aqui continua o código, achando uma linha, ele vai conferir de a data de expiração é maior que a data atual, caso sim, então o usuário é permitido logar no sistema e acessar o conteúdo

     $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;   // abre a sessão pro usuario
     header('Location: conteudo');    // manda ele pro conteudo
} else{     // se a data nao for maior ( ou seja, a data de expiração do usuário passou)
    $_SESSION['chamaradm'] = true;    // abre uma sessão novamente (dica: receba essa sessão na pagina de login com um alerta para o usuário contatar um adm e renovar o mes)
    header('Location: login.php');    // manda ele pra pagina de login
    exit();    // finaliza
}
```

Tem bastante coisa errada no código, como eu disse, não sou programador profissional, mas se a função do sistema for funcionar, ele funciona ;)

Obrigado a todos aqueles que passaram o olho nesse tópico e pensaram em algo ou até mesmo comentaram alguma ajuda.

Fui!!